# Dragging a Component inside of a JFrame leaves a trail of copies

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

A lot of posts on here touch on different aspects of this problem, but I just can't seem to find one that fits. I have a `JFrame` with a `JButton` inside of it in absolute position. I've implemented a `DragListener` class here which renders the `JButton` drag-and-droppable, but doing so leaves a cascade of copies (just visual) behind:

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.event.MouseInputAdapter;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;

public class DragListener extends MouseInputAdapter
{
    Point location;
    MouseEvent pressed;
 
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent me)
    {
        pressed = me;
    }
 
    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent me)
    {
        Component component = me.getComponent();
        location = component.getLocation(location);
        int x = location.x - pressed.getX() + me.getX();
        int y = location.y - pressed.getY() + me.getY();
        component.setLocation(x, y);
        // JFrame mainWindow = (JFrame) SwingUtilities.getWindowAncestor(component);
        // mainWindow.invalidate();
        // mainWindow.validate();
        // mainWindow.repaint();
    }
}
```

I've heard a little bit about calling `paintComponent()` on my main `JFrame` in order to refresh the display, which I've tried by calling `getWindowAncestor()` on my button. Doing so freezes my ability to use components, but lets me still move my window.

The second thing I've tried was to invalidate the `JFrame`, revalidate and redraw. This works, but strobes the entire application.

Any other ideas for how I can drag my button without leaving a trail?

**EDIT**

Here's what my `MainFrame`, the main `JFrame` class looks like, along with a few screenshots of the associated behavior. I've also added in a function in a controller where I add the components to my `MainFrame` instance.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.Graphics;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.List;



public class MainFrame extends JFrame {
    Dimension screenSize;
    Dimension appSize;
    int appW;
    int appH;
    int height;
    int width;
    int squareW;
    int squareH;
    int widgetW;
    int widgetH;
    int widgetSpaceW;
    int widgetSpaceH;

    Map<Point, JPanel> widgetGrid = new HashMap<>();
    List<int[]> grid = new ArrayList<>();

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    
    public MainFrame(String title, Dimension numapps) {
        this(title, numapps, Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize());
        
    }

    
    public MainFrame(String title, Dimension numapps, Dimension screenSize) {
        this.setTitle(title);
        this.screenSize = screenSize;
        this.height = (int) screenSize.getHeight();
        this.width = (int) screenSize.getWidth();
        this.appSize = new Dimension((int) (width * .8), (int) (height * .8));
        this.appW = (int) this.getAppSize().getWidth();
        this.appH= (int) this.getAppSize().getHeight();
        this.squareW = (int) (this.getAppW() / numapps.getWidth());
        this.squareH = (int) (this.getAppH() / numapps.getHeight());
        this.widgetW = (int) (squareW * .9);
        this.widgetH = (int) (squareH * .9);
        this.widgetSpaceW = (int) (squareW * .1);
        this.widgetSpaceH = (int) (squareH * .1);
        this.populateGrid();
        this.setPreferredSize(this.getAppSize());
        this.setLocation((int) (this.getWidth() * .1), (int) (this.getHeight() * .1));

        this.isOpaque();
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setUndecorated(true);
        this.setResizable(false);
        this.paintComponents(null);
        this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    }
```

```
public class MainFrameController {
    
    

    public void initMainFrame(MainFrame mf) {
        makeDraggable(mf);
        
        JPanel p = gridJPanel(mf.getAppSize());
        populateGrid(p, mf);
    
        mf.add(p);
        mf.pack();
        
    }


    public JPanel gridJPanel(Dimension size) {
        JPanel gridPanel = new JPanel();
        gridPanel.setLayout(null);
        gridPanel.setPreferredSize(size);
        gridPanel.setOpaque(false);             
        return gridPanel;
    }

    public void populateGrid(JPanel panel, MainFrame mf) {
        List<int[]> grid = mf.getGrid();
        Dimension squareSize = mf.getSquareSize();
        Dimension widgetSize = mf.getWidgetSize();
        Dimension widgetSpace = mf.getWidgetSpace();
        int wDiff = (int) squareSize.getWidth() / 2;
        int hDiff = (int) squareSize.getHeight() / 2;
        for (int[] point : grid) {
            JButton b = new JButton();
            makeDraggable(b);
            System.out.println(point[0] - wDiff);
            b.setBounds((int) (point[0] - wDiff + widgetSpace.getWidth()), (int) (point[1] - hDiff + widgetSpace.getHeight()), (int) (widgetSize.getWidth() - widgetSpace.getWidth()), (int) (widgetSize.getHeight() - 2 * widgetSpace.getHeight()));
            panel.add(b);
        }
    }

    

    public void makeDraggable(Component c) {
        if (c instanceof MainFrame) {
            MainFrameDragListener dl = new MainFrameDragListener();
            c.addMouseListener(dl);
            c.addMouseMotionListener(dl);
        } else {
            DragListener dl = new DragListener();
            c.addMouseListener(dl);
            c.addMouseMotionListener(dl);
        }
    }
```

[Initial layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tq3oD.png)

[Layout after dragging](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pQlU4.png)

Comment: Consider posting a [mcve].

Comment: How is the user supposed to see the dragging effect without the trail of JButtons?

Comment: Since the UI code is not provided, it is hard to tell; however one suggestion is to add a JPanel in the content pane of the JFrame and at the end of mouseDragged and mousePressed call repaint() of the JPanel. You could check.

Comment: *"Dragging a Component.."* ***.. Why?*** As in, what does the ability to drag a component provide to the user of the software? The only logical thing I can think of is a type of 'drag and drop' GUI design. Only programmers would need that, and even then it is a sub-optimal way to make a GUI, of which there are already too many IDEs offering 'working' versions.

Comment: *"I've heard a little bit about calling `paintComponent()` on my main `JFrame`.."*  It seems you did not actually try that, at least, not with the `@Override` notation.

Comment: @AndrewThompson I have, but I'm not sure if I was able to do so correctly.

Comment: *"I'm not sure if I was able to do so correctly"* The compiler would have issued a warning if the `@Override` notation was correctly used, so .. no. BTW: `this.paintComponents(null);` Ugh.. what tutorial are you looking at? NVM. Stop looking at it & forget the URL. That single line contains two mistakes. Never call `paintComponents`, `paintComponent` or `paint` directly, and never pass a `null` `Graphics` object to them.